# unable to install jdk-7u25-linux-i586.rpm on Centos 6 - unpack200 error

Tags: java, rpm, centos6

On Centos 6, when I do

```
rpm -i jdk-7u25-linux-i586.rpm
```

I get dozens of messages like:

```
/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/unpack200: error while loading shared libraries: libgcc_s.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

but when I do:
'yum install libgcc' I get: 'Package libgcc-4.4.7-3.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version'
I've tried other JDK packages, such as 7.0_21 with the same result.
What should I try next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you have a 64-bit machine, and you're trying to install the 32-bit version of Java. To do that, you'll need to install the `libgcc.i686` package to get the 32-bit runtime libraries. Not sure why you don't already have them.